# As tags [composer] e [composer.json] podem ser unificadas?

Tags: debate, status-pronto, tags

Ambas estão associadas à ferramenta [Composer](https://getcomposer.org/), cujo principal arquivo de configuração é `composer.json`. Algumas perguntas utilizam as duas tags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você tem razão, a tag [composer.json](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/composer.json) é específica demais e desnecessária. Além do mais, só tinha duas perguntas nela, também marcadas com [composer](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/composer). As duas tags agora são sinônimas.